# converting a working jquery soundboard to an object

Tags: jquery

here you can see what I created first: http://justinradford.com/bttf

Here is what I have so far, I will bold the part that is not working

The current problem is when I hit the next button it keeps going back to the second spot in the array of sounds and pics

```
//-----------------------------------------API-------------------------//

    var justinAPI = {
    currentPlay: 0,
    currentImg: 0,
    sound_id: 0,
    image_id: 0,
    next:0,
    i: 0,
    sounds:["1.wav","2.wav","3.wav","4.wav","5.wav","6.wav","7.wav","8.wav","9.wav","10.wav","11.wav","12.wav","13.wav","14.wav","15.wav","16.wav","17.wav","18.wav","19.wav","20.wav"],
    pics:["1.png","2.png","3.png","4.png","5.png","6.png","7.png","8.png","9.png","10.png","11.png","12.png","13.png","14.png","15.png","16.png","17.png","18.png","19.png","20.png"],

    //Click On Image To PLAY
    playIt: function(num){

        this.sound_id =num+".wav";
        this.image_id =num+".png";

        $("#myplayer").attr("src", this.sound_id);
        $("#myplayer")[0].play();


        $("#activeImg").attr("src", this.image_id);

        //this.image_id =$(this).attr("src");
        this.currentPlay = this.sound_id;
        this.currentImg = this.image_id;
    },

    //NEXT button

    nextIt: function(num){
        for (this.i in this.sounds){
        console.log(this.i);
        console.log(this.sounds);
        /* if (this.sounds[i] == this.currentPlay){

                if (i == 19 ){
                    console.log();
                    i=-1;
                    $("#myplayer").attr("src", sounds[i]);
                    $("#activeImg").attr("src", pics[i]);
                }
            */

            **this.next = parseInt(this.i+1);
            this.currentPlay = this.sounds[this.next];**
            $("#myplayer").attr("src", this.sounds[this.next]);
            $("#myplayer")[0].play();
            //$("#activeImg").attr("src", this.pics[this.next]);
            $("#activeImg").attr("src", this.pics[this.currentPlay]);
            break;



                }
            }
        }
    //}





$(".doit").click(function(){
    justinAPI.playIt($(this).attr("id"));
});

$("#next").click(function(){
    justinAPI.nextIt($(this).attr("id"));
    console.log(justinAPI.currentPlay);
});
```

});

Comment: Why does `nextIt()` need a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you want something like this :

```
var justinAPI = {
    i: 0,
    sounds:["1.wav","2.wav","3.wav","4.wav","5.wav","6.wav","7.wav","8.wav","9.wav","10.wav","11.wav","12.wav","13.wav","14.wav","15.wav","16.wav","17.wav","18.wav","19.wav","20.wav"],
    pics:["1.png","2.png","3.png","4.png","5.png","6.png","7.png","8.png","9.png","10.png","11.png","12.png","13.png","14.png","15.png","16.png","17.png","18.png","19.png","20.png"],
    //Click On Image To PLAY
    playIt: function(num) {
        $("#myplayer").attr("src", this.sounds[num]).get(0).play();
        $("#activeImg").attr("src", this.pics[num]);
        this.i = num;
    },
    nextIt: function() {
        this.playIt( (this.i + 1) % this.sounds.length );
    },
    getCurrent: function() {
        return {
            i: this.i,
            sound: this.sounds[this.i],
            img: this.pics[this.i]
        };
    }
}
```

and :

```
$(".doit").click(function() {
    justinAPI.playIt($(this).index());
    console.dir('playIt', justinAPI.getCurrent());
});
$("#next").click(function() {
    justinAPI.nextIt();
    console.dir('nextIt', justinAPI.getCurrent());
});
```